# Configuring Linux server onto Windows active directory network

Tags: windows-server-2003

Have configured the Linux server onto the network, and can ping the windows server: but, cannot see the share created on the Linux server from the windows server. What do I need to do to correct this situation?????

Comment: Very poor question so far, have you setup something like Samba on the Linux box? if so have you added the Linux box to a workgroup or AD?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your linux distro you will need an smbclient, samba and a few other tools to share anything linux ==> Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Vi your /etc/samba/smb.conf

```
Change your work group to match your AD domain. 
Change security to AD. Avoid wins at all costs.
```

Vi your /etc/krb5.conf

```
Change your Realm and KDC's to match your AD domain controllers, validate with your service records. 
Test with kinit.
```

net ads join $domain